# Train model python

Tags: python

I'm trying to train my model with csv data .
My code is bellow

```
dataset =pd.read_csv ('C:/Users/21622/AOI/data.csv', decimal=",")
z = dataset.iloc[:,0:3].values
RESULTS_FOLDER='C:/random forest'
model_path = os.path.join(RESULTS_FOLDER, 'modele rf1.pkl')
model = joblib.load(model_path)
predrf1 = model.predict(z)
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'VV'
```

here some line of my data

```
VV,VH,NDVI
-17.037088,0,-0.56723714
-17.711533,0,-0.5815085
-20.695002,0,-0.58773005
-24.291254,-26.477612,-0.55279505
-18.98536,-22.503922,-0.58133674
-16.514977,-23.752464,-0.5769231
-17.365822,-30.861477,-0.5322377
-18.320848,-33.36731,-0.54140127
-18.19453,-35.388615,-0.53240156
-20.024414,-35.38232,-0.5320262
-24.593035,-29.195107,-0.49866664
```

Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `decimal=","`. It is for when in some countries like Germany that use 0,001 instead of 0.001. But in your case the decimal is already the standard "." and the delimiter is also the standard ",". Just use

```
dataset = pd.read_csv ('C:/Users/21622/AOI/data.csv')
```

Comment: Even when I put like this , the problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is your header `VV, VH, NDVI` which is the main reason of error.

Your error lies in this line:

```py
z = dataset.iloc[:,0:3].values
```

Here you are taking the first row also. So change this line to something like this:

```py
z = dataset.iloc[1:,0:3].values
```

Comment: Even when I put like this , the problem is not solved

Comment: @mhmr I accidently posted wrong answer. Please consider my updated answer :)

Comment: Thank you but , I still have the same error :/

Comment: @mhmr can you upload the csv dataset in drive and share that link here?

Comment: @mhmr is your problem solved? If not upload dataset in drive and share here

Comment: @mhmr you can also help me by ticking my answer :)